# How to make the Linker see files that aren't in the solution

Tags: c, visual-studio, linker, linker-errors, visual-studio-2022

I understand there are similar questions to the one I'm about to ask, but none of the solutions worked for me, and the other questions don't describe my situation in particular.

This is my exact situation: I am using Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition. I have a solution. In this solution, I have 3 projects. Outside of the solution context (but inside the solution folder), I have a folder that contains the **.h** and the respective **.c** files, where I have some structs, functions and defines, that I want to share between my projects, meaning, I would include some (or all) of the **.h** in the different files of a project (**#include "path_to_file\file1.h"** , ...), to have access to the code in those files, and the same in my other projects.

I managed to get this working by manually adding the files I needed, to each project, as a **"Existing Item"**. This is, however, horrible, simply because it's not a scalable solution to my problem. All I would like to do is, for each project (or the entire solution but I don't think that would be possible since each project is built separately), **tell the linker the relative path to that folder** which contains the **.h** and **.c** files that don't belong to the solution, and they would be considered during linking.

If adding the files somehow to the **solution** would make the problem simpler, I'm willing to do that, the nature of the situation allows this.

I tried messing with the projects Properties. I added the relative paths to both the **C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories** (I added $(SolutionDir)\global, global is the name of the folder where the files are), I also added in the **Linker > General > Additional Library Directories** (the same thing I added above). Nothing really solved the Linker errors I'm getting. The IDE finds the files fine, code natigates to the declarations and definitions when I use them in the project, even auto-complete works, but when I try to build, the Linker never finds anything. These are the errors I'm getting:

source.obj : **error LNK2019**: unresolved external symbol CheckNullVa referenced in function Init
source.obj : **error LNK2019**: unresolved external symbol InRange referenced in function LoadInitialValues
(...)

Basically, errors for each of the functions I try to use that came from these solution external files.

I also tried to make a new project in the solution, add the files there, and try again setting the same properties in the projects I wanted to include them, and also right clicking the projects **Build Dependencies > Project Dependencies...** and checking the box next to this new project I created containing the files. This resulted in the exact same problem.

I was only able to get this to work by manually adding file-by-file to each of the projects I wanted to access the files, via **Add > Existing Item...**
This works, but it's not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: You are asking "what are static libraries and how do I define them using Visual Studio" - the answer to the second half being: "C++ support in Visual Studio is quite bad - use CMake or another ***generator*** to create the project structure for you". You'll otherwise have to add linker and compiler search paths individually by hand.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-170

Comment: @Ext3h I understand Visual Studio C and C++ support is not the greatest. Adding Linker and Compiler search path by hand still failed in my situation, hence why I asked for help here. I will take a look at the documentation you linked.

Comment: @Ext3h the link you provided solved my issue, thank you a bunch. If you make it a answer I can mark it as a solution, or if this question has a duplicate answer in another thread, feel free to mark it as duplicate and redirect people to that other thread.
Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.